# Object destructuring default using other destructured values

Tags: ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

The follow works in node `v8.11.4` and in babel transpiled JavaScript running on chrome

```
const myFunc = ({
  aryOfObjs,
  combinedObj = Object.assign({}, ...aryOfObjs),
}) => console.log(combinedObj);
myFunc({
  aryOfObjs: [
    { foo: 'bar'},
    { biz: 'baz' },
  ]
}); // => { foo: 'bar', biz: 'baz' }
```

In EMACScript 2015 is this guaranteed to work as shown above?

I know node and babel aren't 100% EMACScript 2015 complaint but I believe they both implement the object destructuring spec I can't find anything explicit on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) that says this is supported nor on the official [ECMAScript 2015 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is valid ES2015 code. `aryOfObjs` is a variable introduced into the function scope, and `Object.assign({}, ...aryOfObjs)` is an expression evaluated in that scope so it can access any of those variables. The only time this would be an error is if they were accessed out of order, like

```
const myFunc = ({
  combindedObj = Object.assign({}, ...aryOfObjs),
  aryOfObjs,
}) => console.log(combindedObj);
```

which would throw an error because `aryOfObjs` has not been initialized yet.